# Two Java methods for easy writing and reading bytes in files

Tags: java, file, reinventing-the-wheel

I have these easy-to-use methods for reading and writing binary data in files.

**FileTools.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.file;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class contains utility methods for writing and reading binary data in 
 * files.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov 
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 29, 2016)
 */
public class FileTools {

    /**
     * This method returns the byte array that represent the contents of 
     * {@code file}.
     * 
     * @param  file the file to read.
     * @return the array of bytes representing the contents of the input file.
     */
    public static byte[] readFile(File file) 
    throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(file, "The input file is null.");
        long size = file.length();
        checkSize(size);

        byte[] data;
        int bytesRead;

        try (FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            data = new byte[(int) size];
            bytesRead = stream.read(data);
        }

        if (bytesRead != size) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "File size and read count mismatch. File size: " +
                    size + ", bytes read: " + bytesRead);
        }

        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Writes the byte array {@code data} to the file {@code file}. After 
     * successful operation of this method, the input file will contain exactly
     * the contents of the input data.
     * 
     * @param file the file to write to.
     * @param data the data array to write.
     * @throws java.io.IOException           if file IO fails.
     * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException if file does not exist.
     */
    public static void writeFile(File file, byte[] data)
    throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(file, "The input file is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(data, "The input data to write is null.");

        try (BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                                           new FileOutputStream(file))) {
            stream.write(data);
        }
    }

    // This method ensures that file size is small enough to be represented 
    // using a variable of type 'int'.
    private static final void checkSize(long size) {
        if (size > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "The target file is too large: " + size + " bytes. " +
                    "Maximum allowed size is " + Integer.MAX_VALUE + 
                    "bytes.");
        }
    }
}
```

**FileToolsTest.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.file;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class FileToolsTest {

    private static final int ITERATIONS = 100;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH = 20_000;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        long seed = System.nanoTime();
        Random random = new Random(seed);
        System.out.println("Seed = " + seed);

        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i) {

            File file = new File("funky.txt");
            byte[] data = new byte[random.nextInt(MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH)];
            random.nextBytes(data);

            try {
                FileTools.writeFile(file, data);
                byte[] result = FileTools.readFile(file);
                assertTrue(Arrays.equals(result, data));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                fail(ex.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                fail(ex.getMessage());
            }

            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

From your "reinventing-the-wheel" tag, I assume you're already aware of [Guava's](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html) and [Apache Commons'](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) utilities. So my only nitpick is that the `int` cast might be clearer if it was closer to the size check:

```
long sizeLong = file.length();
checkSize(sizeLong);
int size = (int)sizeLong;
```

Or if you want to be a little more "clever":

```
int size = checkSize(file.length());
//...
private static final int checkSize(long size) {
    //...
    return (int)size;
}
```